# Model Binding not working if GUID is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

In the following Code Snippet, the ExpenseRecord object is always null when I make a POST request with the body: `{"id":null,"name":"Test","reason":"Flight","date":"01.10.2016","amount":10,"text":"Test"}`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]ExpenseRecord record)
{
    try
    {
        this.repository.Create(record);
        return this.Created($"api/expenses/{record.Id}", null);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        return this.BadRequest();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
    }
 }
```

The ExpenseRecord looks like:

```
public class ExpenseRecord : IEquatable<ExpenseRecord>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ExpenseReason Reason { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If the ID is set to a proper fomatted GUID is works. However, when posting a new record, I can't (or rather don't want) to provide a ID?

Comment: How you made POST request?

Comment: Advanced Rest Client:
POST /api/expenses HTTP/1.1
HOST: localhost:57938
content-type: application/json
content-length: 89

{"id":null,"name":"Test","reason":"Flight","date":"01.10.2016","amount":10,"text":"Test"}

Comment: `Guid` is a `struct`, hence cannot allow null values.

Comment: Is there an appropriate solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was said, a guid can't be null.

```
// change
public Guid Id { get; set; }

// to
public Guid? Id { get; set; }
```

or send an empty guid in your POST